# Unlock keyring of auto-logged-in user

Tags: fedora, screen-sharing, gnome-keyring

I want to be able to access my GNOME desktop remotely. The problem is that GNOME's screen sharing is using the keyring to store its password. As a result for sharing to work, the logged in user must unlock the GNOME keyring.

My problem is that I have auto-login enabled and therefore my keyring stays locked when the system starts and the desktop is displayed. I am able to start screen sharing from the CLI using an SSH connection with:

```
# allow screen control
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.remote-desktop.vnc view-only false
# use password authentication for VNC
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.remote-desktop.vnc auth-method 'password'
# start sharing service
systemctl --user start gnome-remote-desktop
```

Unfortunately the if I try to connect the password exchange fails as gnome-remote-desktop is unable to access the keyring. I tried setting the password from SSH to something new with secret-tool but I get the same error:

```
$ echo -n "random_pass" | secret-tool store --label="GNOME Remote Desktop VNC password" "xdg:schema" "org.gnome.RemoteDesktop.VncPassword"
secret-tool: Cannot create an item in a locked collection
```

I tried unlocking the keyring from command-line but this does not seem to work:

```
$ read -p "Enter your password: " -s pw && ( echo $pw | gnome-keyring-daemon --unlock )
Enter your password: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
```

I still can't get secret-tool to access the keyring. I also installed a package called `dnf install python3-keyring` but it also fails to unlock:

```
[user@fedora ~]$ keyring set "xdg:schema" "org.gnome.RemoteDesktop.VncPassword"
Password for 'org.gnome.RemoteDesktop.VncPassword' in 'xdg:schema':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/keyring", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('keyring==21.8.0', 'console_scripts', 'keyring')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyring/cli.py", line 133, in main
    return cli.run(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyring/cli.py", line 88, in run
    set_password(service, username, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyring/core.py", line 60, in set_password
    get_keyring().set_password(service_name, username, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyring/backends/SecretService.py", line 87, in set_password
    collection = self.get_preferred_collection()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyring/backends/SecretService.py", line 67, in get_preferred_collection
    raise KeyringLocked("Failed to unlock the collection!")
keyring.errors.KeyringLocked: Failed to unlock the collection!
```

NOTE: all this is on Fedora 35

To recap, my question is: How do I unlock the keyring of a user that has automatically logged in at boot, using only an SSH shell made via a VPN connection?

EDIT: Forgot to mention something important. Removing the keyring password (so that it is unprotected) fixes the issue, but the point here is to keep a keyring password.

Comment: The only solution seems to be to remove the password. This should not matter if your system is encrypted, as the keyring will in any case only protect you against passive attacks.

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/SecurityPhilosophy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a workable solution in [this post from UNIX stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602313/unlock-gnome-keyring-daemon-from-command-line). Basically, create a script **which must be sourced** from an SSH remote login session:

```
echo 'NOTE: This script will only work if launched via source or .' >&2
echo -n 'Login password: ' >&2
read -s _UNLOCK_PASSWORD || return
killall -q -u "$(whoami)" gnome-keyring-daemon
eval $(echo -n "${_UNLOCK_PASSWORD}" \
           | gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login \
           | sed -e 's/^/export /')
unset _UNLOCK_PASSWORD
echo '' >&2
```